# jquery deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am having trouble learning to use the new jQuery Deferred.

The does an ajax call and i want to return the data of the ajax call.

```
checkIDExists = function(id){
    var exists = false;
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            method: "idExists",
            id: id
        },
        success: function(data){
                if(data == 'true'){
                    exists = true;
                }
        }
    }).done(function(){
        return exists;
    }).fail(function(){
        return false;
    });
};
```

I know the problem comes in when i try to return something inside of the done() or fail() functions which doesn't return it for the checkIdExists() function. How do i work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax itself works asynchronously, so function checkIDExists completes earlier then ajax call returns data from the server.

In your case I wouldn't rely on return value of checkIDExists function, but I would overwrite the function using [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) approach.

Answer (score 4):

The statements by Lloyd are correct as far as I know, but I dont think that was exactly the answer you were looking for, here's my attempt:

First off, when working with deferred promises the only reasonable thing to expect and provide as a return value is a promise object (hence why Lloyd points you to CPS).

Where you would *normally* do something like

```
/* Have some kind of callback for when ajax is done */

var myCompleteCallback = function(data){
   // whatever you want to do with your ajax call results
}

var myErrorCallback = function(){
   // handle the ajax error
}

/* Send the actual ajax request, and tell it to call MyCompleteCallback afterwards */

  $.ajax({
    url: '/foo/bar.xml'
    data: {},
    success: myCompleteCallback,
    error: 
  });
```

You would do like such in a deffered-style implementaion:

```
/* Have some kind of callback for when promise is resolved is done */

var myCompleteCallback = function(data){
   // whatever you want to do with your ajax call results
}

var myErrorCallback = function(){
   // handle the ajax error
}

/* you could also do ajax.done().fail() but i think this reads better as an example */

var getsomething = $.ajax({ url: '/foo/bar.xml', data: {} });
getsomething.then( myCompleteCallback, myErrorCallback )
```

So as you see, there's nothing much magical and different about it except when you start getting into more complex examples.

Whats cool about it though (following from previous example)...

```
var getVisitorInfo = function(){

  /* stash the user information ajax call promise */

  var fetchUserInfo    = $.ajax({url:"/some/api/user.json"})

  /* stash the account information ajax call promise */

  var fetchAccountInfo = $.ajax({url:"/some/api/user.json"})

  /* trigger both calls and returns a promise that will resolve to both results */

  return $.when( fetchUserInfo,  fetchAccountInfo )
}

/* Usage: */

getVisitorInfo().done(function(userJSON, accountJSON){
   // manipulate your data/ui/and whatnot
}).fail(function(failure1,failure2){
   // redirect to login or whatever
})
```

Hope this helps. I'd suggest taking a look at various deferred/promise implementations to get a better understanding of it all. What REALLY helped me was playing around with [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library (and the fine quality README he provides) and reading about it on the [CommonJS wiki](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises). And Kris also gave a  [talk on the topic back in 2010](http://askawizard.blogspot.com/2010/12/this-year-at-jsconf.html)